# Count Unique Data With Minimum Date Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a problem while trying to count data in my table.

for example my table look like this:

```
table = test
id       | transaction_date
1        | '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
2        | '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
3        | '2021-10-02 00:00:00'
4        | '2021-10-03 00:00:00'
5        | '2021-10-04 00:00:00'
6        | '2021-10-05 00:00:00'
7        | '2021-10-06 00:00:00'

1        | '2021-11-01 00:00:00'
2        | '2021-11-01 00:00:00'
3        | '2021-11-02 00:00:00'

1        | '2021-12-01 00:00:00'
2        | '2021-12-01 00:00:00'
3        | '2021-12-02 00:00:00'
4        | '2021-12-03 00:00:00'
8        | '2021-12-04 00:00:00'
8        | '2021-12-05 00:00:00'
9        | '2021-12-06 00:00:00'
9        | '2021-12-07 00:00:00'
```

I tried to use this query

```
WITH first_transaction_AS (SELECT MIN(transaction_date), id FROM test),
previous_month AS (SELECT DISTINCT idFROM test 
WHERE transaction_date >= date_trunc('month', transaction_date)-interval '1 month' 
AND transaction_date < date_trunc('month', transaction_date)

-- WHERE clause for previous month will be dynamic

SELECT date_trunc('month', transaction_date), COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM test 
WHERE test.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM previous_month) AND transaction_date NOT IN (SELECT min FROM first_transaction)
```

I wanted to achieve a aggregate query where:
Count ID Where ID has Transaction this month AND ID Without Transaction Last Month AND It's not the ID's First Transaction

The current problem is, ID 8 and 9 Will still be count Because they has a transaction after their first transaction in the same month.

So what i aim for the result is:

```
    Date                    |         Count
  2021-12-01 00:00:00       |           1  (4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 1 according the rules.

> ```
> select 
>   date(date_trunc('month', transaction_date)) as "Date"
> , count(distinct id) as "Count"
> from test t
> where transaction_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date)
>   and transaction_date < (date_trunc('month', current_date)+interval '1 month') 
>   and not exists ( -- not previous month
>       select 1
>       from test t2
>       where t2.id = t.id
>         and t2.transaction_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
>         and t2.transaction_date <  date_trunc('month', current_date)
>   
>   )
>   and exists ( -- created previously
>       select 1
>       from test t2
>       where t2.id = t.id
>         and t2.transaction_date <  date_trunc('month', current_date)
>   )
> group by date_trunc('month', transaction_date)
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | Count
> :--------- | ----:
> 2021-12-01 |     1
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6108cd84a97306d8d7fd4903732f0865)*

Comment: nice way to get it. but if i try it with more data it gives me timeout. any other way other than using self join method? thanks

Comment: @YohanesLim Could check the explain of the query. Maybe needs an index? But I've changed the fiddle. There's extra where a temporary table is used. Basically cutting the logic up.